# How to search for a keyword in a list of strings, and return that string?

Tags: python, list, search, cpu-word

I have a list of strings that are a few words long, and I need to search for two keywords, and return the strings that contain those two key words.

I have tried to loop through the strings, but was not able to do so. I tried the .find() function but that was not successful on a list of strings.

Lets say we have a list:

```
list = ["The man walked the dog", "The lady walked the dog","Dogs 
are cool", "Cats are interesting creatures", "Cats and Dogs was an 
interesting movie", "The man has a brown dog"]
```

I would like to iterate through the list of strings and return the strings in a new list that contain both the words "man" and "dog". Ideally, to get the following:

```
list_new = ["The man walked the dog", "The man has a brown dog"]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this :

```
list_ = ["The man walked the dog", "The lady walked the dog","Dogs are cool", "Cats are interesting creatures", "Cats and Dogs was an interesting movie", "The man has a brown dog"]
l1 = [k for k in list_ if 'man' in k and 'dog' in k]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
['The man walked the dog', 'The man has a brown dog']
```

Note : Refrain from assigning variable name as `list`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a regex to avoid matchings with words like *manifold* or *dogma*:

```
import re

l = [
    "The man walked the dog", 
    "The lady walked the dog", 
    "Dogs are cool", 
    "Cats are interesting creatures",
    "Cats and Dogs was an interesting movie", 
    "The man has a brown dog",
    "the manner dogma"
]

words = ["man", "dog"]
results = [x for x in l if all(re.search("\\b{}\\b".format(w), x) for w in words)]
results

>>> ['The man walked the dog', 'The man has a brown dog']
```

Comment: A more complex regex would let you remove punctuation too. e. g. 'The man walked the dog.'

Comment: this regex matches 'dog' in your example. Do you think it shouldn't?

Comment: I didn't expect '\\b' to match punctuation.  I've learned something new.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
words = ["man", "dog"]
l = ["The man walked the dog", "The lady walked the dog","Dogs are cool", "Cats are interesting creatures", "Cats and Dogs was an interesting movie", "The man has a brown dog"]
new_list = [item for item in l if all((word in item) for word in words)]
```

gives

```
['The man walked the dog', 'The man has a brown dog']
```

(I didn't use the name `list` since that would mask the built-in type.)