# How to search for a list of keywords in a series of strings using Python?

Tags: python

I am about to lose my mind. I'm fairly new to Python but I can usually brute force my way through.  My code is never elegant, but I can usually solve whatever simple problems I have using what I learned from 'How to Automate the Boring Stuff with Python'.

Here's my problem:

I have a list of keywords and a list of strings.  I want to search for each keyword in each of the strings.  I want to return the whole string when a keyword is present in the string.

This is a boiled down version of what I'm trying to do:

```
spam = ['tyler is cool', 'lucy eats cool pasta']
eggs = ['tyler', 'pasta']

for i in range(len(spam)):
    for k in range(len(eggs)):
        print(eggs[k] in spam[i])
        if eggs[k] in spam[i] == True:
            print('please work')
        else:
            print('why doesn\'t this work')
```

My output looks like this:

```
True
why doesn't this work
False
why doesn't this work
False
why doesn't this work
True
why doesn't this work
```

If the statement is returning as `True`, why am I getting the "else" solution?

I've tried [How to search for a keyword in a list of strings, and return that string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55893314/how-to-search-for-a-keyword-in-a-list-of-strings-and-return-that-string) and [Search a list of list of strings for a list of strings in python efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316970/search-a-list-of-list-of-strings-for-a-list-of-strings-in-python-efficiently) and it's not working.  I'm stuck.  Please help.

Comment: `eggs[k] in spam[i] == True` means `eggs[k] in spam[i] and spam[i] == True`. You should just have `if eggs[k] in spam[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `== True`

Use:

```py
if eggs[k] in spam[i]
```

---

**Edit:**

You are getting the Else solution because using the expression you mentioned (`if eggs[k] in spam[i] == True`): you are checking if `eggs[k] in spam[i] and spam[i] == True` because of operator chaining

Also good to check [this question about == vs is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276610/boolean-identity-true-vs-is-true)

Comment: Did not answer "why am I getting the "else" solution?".

Comment: thanks for that, @Enzo

Comment: Your explanation is not quite right. `eggs[k] in spam[i] == True` means `eggs[k] in spam[i] and spam[i] == True` because of operator chaining.